# Rails grouped_collection :selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grouped-collection-select

The following works for having the current user's primary workgroup selected in a dropdown:

```
        <%= f.association :workgroup, :collection => Workgroup.all, :label_method => :group_name, :label => '1) Work Group', :selected => current_user.employee.priworkgroup_id %>
```

But, how do you set a `:selected` for  grouped_collection_select ?

Code attempts:

```
        <%= f.grouped_collection_select :employee_id, Workgroup.order(:id), :employees, :group_name, :id, :employee_full_name, :selected => current_user.employee.id %>

        <%= f.grouped_collection_select :employee_id, Workgroup.order(:id), :employees, :group_name, :id, :employee_full_name, :include_blank => true, :selected => [current_user.employee.priworkgroup_id, current_user.employee.id] %>
```

UPDATE1

Reading about grouped_collection_select, I found selected_key

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :employee_id, Workgroup.order(:id), :employees, :group_name, :id, :employee_full_name, :include_blank => true, :selected_key => current_user.employee.id %>
```

`current_user.employee.id` is = 5

Inspecting the html, the user I want selected has this:

```
<option value="5">John Jones</option>
```

UPDATE - thanks to Fenec.

I used the following:

```
<% options = option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Workgroup.order(:id),
       :employees, :group_name, :id, :employee_full_name, current_user.employee.id) %>
<%= select(:employee_id, :employees, options, include_blank: true) %>
```

And it displays correctly on the screen.  But, the select doesn't update the data in the record.

I changed to this:

```
<%= f.select(:employee_id, :employees, options, include_blank: true) %>
```

And got `undefined method`merge'`

Comment: try using this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817496/how-to-use-selected-with-grouped-collection-select

Comment: #Fenec - that works!  Seems confusing to me - but, hey it works.  Thanks!  If you want points, I'm willing to give them to you.  Reddirt.

Comment: Great. Rails helpers are often confusing when they have so many options to set. You better save your points for some real answer, I just posted a link.

Comment: #Fenec - I ran into an issue = the `select` shows on the screen correctly, but it isn't a form input.  I changed it `f.select` and got undefined method `merge'.  What should I change the select to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
<% options = option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Workgroup.order(:id),
       :employees, :group_name, :id, :employee_full_name, current_user.employee.id) %>

<%= f.select(:employee_id,  options, include_blank: true) %>
```